# Why are FormGroup controls null after formGroup.reset()?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have this reactive form that I'm setting up with:

```
const v = Validators;

this.entryForm = this.formBuilder.group({

  firstName: ['', [v.minLength(2), v.required]],
  lastName: ['', [v.minLength(2), v.required]],
  email: ['', [v.email, v.required]],
  instagram: ['', [v.minLength(2), v.required]],
  company: [''],
  title: [''],
  agree: [false, v.requiredTrue],

});
```

But after I call `this.entryForm.reset()`, like:

```
this.entryForm.reset();
```

...the form controls of `entryForm` are `null`, causing errors. Even if I try re-instantiating the `FormGroup`, I still see `null` form controls. What the heck am I doing wrong?

Here is the complete component TypeScript:

```
@Component({
  selector: 's2es-enter-page',
  templateUrl: './enter-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './enter-page.component.sass',
  ]
})
export class EnterPageComponent extends AbstractPageComponent implements OnInit {

  entryForm: FormGroup;
  inited = false;

  constructor(
    private readonly pageService: PageService,
    private readonly http: HttpClient,
    private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    super(pageService);

    this.entryForm = new FormGroup({
      first: new FormControl(),
    });

    (window as any).localJsonpCallback = () => {
      this.entryForm.reset();
    };
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyRrxv8Ri-GRpuXqWXo2inCPzmAE8mG6Q8oQIGPmUeMaGbD5jCn/exec?';
    const q: string[] = [];
    const company = this.entryForm.get('company').value + ',' + this.entryForm.get('title').value;
    const name = this.entryForm.get('firstName').value + ',' + this.entryForm.get('lastName').value;

    q.push('name=' + name);
    q.push('email=' + this.entryForm.get('email').value);
    q.push('instagram=' + this.entryForm.get('instagram').value);
    if (company.length > 1) { q.push('company=' + company); }
    q.push('prefix=localJsonpCallback');

    const uri = url + q.join('&');
    this.http.jsonp(uri, 'JSONP_CALLBACK').subscribe((val) => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Since this is not supported on MS browsers.
   */
  placeholderShown(id: string): boolean {
    if (this.inited) {
      if (this.entryForm.get(id).value !== null) {
        return !this.entryForm.get(id).value.length;
      } else {
        // I don't know why this is null.
        // throw new Error(id);
        // return false;
      }
    }
  }

  setupForm() {

    const v = Validators;

    this.entryForm = this.formBuilder.group({

      firstName: ['', [v.minLength(2), v.required]],
      lastName: ['', [v.minLength(2), v.required]],
      email: ['', [v.email, v.required]],
      instagram: ['', [v.minLength(2), v.required]],
      company: [''],
      title: [''],
      agree: [false, v.requiredTrue],

    });
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  ngOnInit() {

    super.ngOnInit();

    this.setupForm();

    this.inited = true;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Official documentation ([See here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#reset)) actually claims, that controls *will* be set to null. There is no need to reset form after it's creation though. If you wish to fill it with other values (like `''`), you can call `reset` with `formState` parameter set to desired value.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the reset method directly will reset the form to `null`. To reset with predefined values,

Reset using the following code:

```
this.entryForm.reset({
    firstName: ['', [v.minLength(2), v.required]],
    lastName: ['', [v.minLength(2), v.required]],
    email: ['', [v.email, v.required]],
    instagram: ['', [v.minLength(2), v.required]],
    company: [''],
    title: [''],
    agree: [false, v.requiredTrue],
});
```

Answer (score -2):

reset(); is use to reset it as default state as it initiated.
reset() is used to clear the form.

so, if you want to get value from it you can use on ngSubmit="saveForm()"

in the saveForm method you can get value

this.entryForm.controls.firstName.value

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I *AM* trying to reset my form to the default, initial values.